# How to clean DB with Rails 5, Minitest, Capybara JS (Selenium)?

Tags: selenium, capybara, minitest, ruby-on-rails-5

I have set up a very simple rails 5 project to narrow down my problem: 
https://github.com/benedikt-voigt/capybara_js_demo

In this project the data mutation done by the Capybara JS is not deleted, neither by Rails nor by the Database cleaner I added.

The following great blog argues, that no DatabaseCleaner is needed:
http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/7-reasons-why-im-sticking-with-minitest-and-fixtures-in-rails
but this works only for fixtures, not for the mutation done by an out-of-thread Capybara test.
I added the Database cleaner, but this also needed work.

Does anybody has a sample setup?

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look at your test I would say it's leaving data because the data is actually being added after DatabaseCleaner cleans.  The `click_on` call occurs asynchronously, so when your `assert_no_content` call happens there's no guarantee the app has handled the request yet or the page has changed yet and since the current page doesn't have the text 'Name has already been taken' on it the assertion passes and the database gets cleaned.  While that is happening the click gets processed by the app and the new data is created after the cleaning has occurred.  You need to check/wait for content that will appear on the page after the click - something like

```
page.assert_text('New Foo Created')
```

You should only be asserting there is no content once you already know the page has changed, or you're expecting something to disappear from the current page.

Comment: Tom, thanks for looking at it. I tried it out and changed the assertion, but this doesn't solve the problem. The problem is still, that the created objects are not removed from the DB. Even after the test suite run through, this data still remains in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I solved now the problem by setting the DB connection to one

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  mattr_accessor :shared_connection
  @@shared_connection = nil

  def self.connection
    @@shared_connection || ConnectionPool::Wrapper.new(:size => 1) { retrieve_connection }
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
```

as describe here:
https://mattbrictson.com/minitest-and-rails

I uploaded the working repo here:
https://github.com/benedikt-voigt/capybara_js_demo_working